# Value of User Defined Table type in stored procedure while debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stored-procedures, visual-studio-debugging, user-defined-types

I am trying to debug stored procedure through `Visual Studio 2015` and would like to see value of `User Defined Table type`.

Script of User Defined Table Type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[tp_CommercialActCarSends] AS TABLE(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ArriveDate] VARCHAR(25) NULL,
    [id_Person] [int] NULL,
    [CalcWeight] [DECIMAL](18,3) NULL   
)
GO
```

And code of stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure](
    , @CommercialActCarSends        tp_CommercialActCarSends READONLY
        , @UserID                       INT = NULL
)
AS
...
```

I populate ‘DataTable’ object ‘comActsDataTable’ with some data and pass the ‘comActsDataTable’ to the stored procedure through C#:

```
var reqRes = db.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>("EXEC dbo.MyStoredProcedure @UserID = @UserID, 
    @CommercialActCarSends = @CommercialActCarSends"
    , InitSqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int, usrid)
    , InitSqlParameter("@CommercialActCarSends", SqlDbType.Structured, comActsDataTable, 
    "tp_CommercialActCarSends")
```

What I see in `Visual Studio` is just:

[image]

Is it possible to see  what values of `tp_CommercialActCarSends` stored procedure received while debugging in Visual Studio?

Comment: Why not create a break point and look at comActsDataTable?

Comment: @SeanLange As I really want to see what I sent to the Stored Procedure to debug errors.

Comment: @SeanLange is it possible to read values of ‘tp_CommercialSctVatSends’ while debugging?

Comment: It would be the same contents as your DataTable. But if you really want to see the contents you would probably need to create a table and insert into that table in your procedure code. Then when it finishes the procedure you could examine the contents of that table. AFAIK you cannot view the actual contents of the parameter value in dotnet when you have a table valued parameter.

Comment: @SeanLange Could you make your comment as an answer and I will mark it! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be the same contents as your DataTable. But if you really want to see the contents you would probably need to create a table and insert into that table in your procedure code. Then when it finishes the procedure you could examine the contents of that table. AFAIK you cannot view the actual contents of the parameter value in dotnet when you have a table valued parameter.